# How to monitor Data In / Out for each request / transaction on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have observed that my Website hosted on Azure Cloud Service has aggregate network out of 24 GB and aggregate network in of 20GB. I am not sure why so much data transfer is happening. Is there any way where I can measure the amount of data transferred for each request / response. This will help me understand which of the requests /  response are taking too much of bandwidth.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your website hosted as an Azure Webapp or Cloud service? In either case, you can look at IIS logs for your site and look at cs-bytes and sc-bytes fields in them.

The best thing to do is download IIS logs locally and run a tool like LogParser as that allow you to sum these fields from the IIS logs.

**sample queries**

```
logparser.exe "select sum(cs-bytes) as clienttoserverbytes , sum(sc-bytes) as ServerToClientBytes from 'c:\iislogs\*.log'" -i:IISW3C
```

The above will show if it is the client to server bytes or server to client bytes which is high and then you can use something like this

```
logparser.exe "select top 500 cs-uri-stem , sum(cs-bytes) as ClientToserverbytes from 'c:\iislogs\*.log' group by cs-uri-stem order by clientToServerbytes DESC" -i:IISW3C -rtp:-1
```

If the sc-bytes is high then replace cs-bytes with sc-bytes in the above query

Comment: Thanks Puneet, I have realized yesterday that I can get this from IIS Logs. Have used Visual Log Parser and able to get the information I need.

Thanks very much your reply.